# Spacing between operators in IEEE document algorithms

Tags: spacing, ieeetran, algorithmic

I use the IEEE format and the algorithmic package.
However, the spacing around binary operators in algorithms is too wide.
attached screenshot:
[image]

using this code:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \STATE $y = \max{[0, x-1]}$ such that $[nic_y,nic_{y+1}]_{N'} \neq [nic_y,nic_{y+1}]_{C'}$

\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  there's really not enough information here for someone else to experiment.  please provide a small example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  (this is called a "minimum (non)working example", or "mwe".)

Comment: I added the code generating the algorithm

Comment: as i thought, what you show is just the first line of a `\STATE` statement that is longer than one line, and the "best" breakpoint is at a location that forces the first line to be stretched.  (in the log, there's a warning about `Underfull \hbox (badness 2245)`)  the manual offers the availability of `\\ ` to break long lines.  a better approach would be to treat the algorithm statement as ragged right, but i haven't found how to do that yet.

Comment: @barbarabeeton has explained the problerm. A possible solution: `\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\nic}{nic}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE $y = \max{[0, x-1]}$ such that  \\
\hspace*{3em}$[\nic_y,\nic_{y+1}]_{N'} \neq [\nic_y,\nic_{y+1}]_{C'}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem.
Why do I need the \DeclareMathOperator{\nic}{nic} ? It works the same without it.

Comment: @Daniel Please see my answer below. It works (apparently) the same, but it gives a different result; with my definition, which is optional and for you to decide whether to use or not, "nic" is typeset in roman (upright) font and the spacing is the one of an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **barbara beeton** has mentioned in [`her comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261119/spacing-between-operators-in-ieee-document-algorithms#comment625918_261119), the problem is that the statement is longer than one line, and the "best" breakpoint is at a location that forces the first line to be stretched.

Below I present two possible solutions: the first one, using a local `\raggedright` and the second one, using a manual line break and some indentation:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\nic}{nic}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE{\raggedright $y = \max{[0, x-1]}$ such that  $[\nic_y,\nic_{y+1}]_{N'} \neq [\nic_y,\nic_{y+1}]_{C'}$\par}
\STATE $y = \max{[0, x-1]}$ such that  \\
\hspace*{3em}$[\nic_y,\nic_{y+1}]_{N'} \neq [\nic_y,\nic_{y+1}]_{C'}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I also introduced

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\nic}{nic}
```

in case your "nic" was some kind of operator, to have the proper typeface but this, of course, it's optional and it depends on the actual meaning of "nic".